# Translating infinite loop with IO operation to observable

Tags: c#, .net-core, io, observable, system.reactive

Hello i am trying to transform a long running task(in which i read from a socket on each iteration) in an `Observable`.This task  receives a `CancellationToken`.

**Some Model**

```
public class Model
{
   public string Data{get;set;}
}
```

**Long running Task**

```
    CancellationTokenSource cts=new CancellationTokenSource();
    ClientWebSocket socket=await ConnectTheWebSocketAsync();
    Task t1=Task.Run(async()=>{
       while(true)
       {
          cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
          byte[] rawInput = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(bufferSize);
          var rec = await socket.ReceiveAsync(rawInput, cts.Token);
          Model result = rawInput.AsMemory().Slice(0, rec.Count).Decode<Model>();  //some wrapper for serialization
          ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(rawInput);
          //i want to push this result into an observable
          //Could i use an Observable.Empty and put data in it here ?
         // myObs.OnNext(result);
       }
    },cts.Token);
```

**Observable Attempt**

I have looked upon ways to create this observable and i have stumbled upon `FromAsync`:

```
 var obs = Observable.FromAsync((cts) => {
                byte[] rawInput = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(bufferSize);
                var rec = await socket.ReceiveAsync(rawInput, cts.Token);
                Model result = rawInput.AsMemory().Slice(0, rec.Count).Decode<Model>();  //some wrapper for serialization
                ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(rawInput);
                return result;

            }).Repeat();
```

- .What i do not understand is how do i put a `CancellationToken` over the `Repeat` if i want the observable to stop.
- .I have seen that `FromAsync` also has an overload with `CancellationToken`.I assume this token would be passed for each
  element , and i would inject it in the socket's `ReceiveAsync` too. This would give me control over the current `ReceiveAsync` operation of the socket or the current element that is getting constructed.Still it won't stop the `Repeat`.

So my question would be:

```
Observable.FromAsync((token)=> [some io action]).Repeat();
```

Given the above pattern:
 - How do i stop a single iteration ( reading from the socket )
 - How do i stop the entire loop (`Repeat`)
 - Where would the token argument of `FromAsync` come from

Comment: You don't need to do a cancellation token on the `.Repeat()` as calling `.Dispose()` on the subscription will cancel the observable. The cancellation token in the `FromAsync` operator is all you need to worry about. It will be triggered when you dispose of the subscription.

Comment: When using a `.Repeat()` you should construct your observable as, so, in your case, `Observable.Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync((token)=> [some io action])).Repeat()`. Try that and see if it helps.When using a `.Repeat()` you should construct your observable as, so, in your case, `Observable.Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync((token)=> [some io action])).Repeat()`. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: An [mcve] would be useful. I couldn't test your current code so I'm not prepared to propose an answer.